# Google maps API V3 - isLocationOnEdge() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge() method. In fiddle, try to click on horizontal line, returns true like expected, but clicking on vertical line returns false. Why?

Thanks!

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bDfpK/) and here is code:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.5, 0.5),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [
      new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
      new google.maps.LatLng(0, 1),
      new google.maps.LatLng(1, 1)
    ],
      map: map
  });

    google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', function(event){
        alert(google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(event.latLng, this), 0.00001);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are better off using `containsLocation()`

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#containsLocation) :

> To find whether a given point falls within a polygon, pass the point
>   and the polygon to google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(). The
>   functions returns true if the point is within the polygon or on its
>   edge.

vs

> To determine whether a point falls on or near a polyline, or on or
>   near the edge of a polygon, pass the point, the polyline/polygon, and
>   optionally a tolerance value in degrees to
>   google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge().

If you use `containsLocation` it works

```js
alert(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng, poly));
```

forked fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VL7Rx/

I really cant explain exactly why it does not working with `isLocationOnEdge`. It seems to be an issue on **100% vertical polylines only**, and with your 0,0,0,1 etc the Lng always is zero (0) (clicking vertical) - as if the line does not have any "width" at all, "mapwise".

Comment: Strange that this is not working, but thanks for your answer, it works!

Comment: Yes, I think too. I looked really hard in google discussions and so on, cannot believe it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

containsLocation works only in the fiddle by davidkonrad if your listener is for clicks on the polyline. If your listener is on the map instead you will get 'true' anywhere in the triangle formed by the 3 LatLngs. If the user can't click the map itself then this is fine, but it may not work for your specific requirement.

Sadly, I can't see why the vertical line isn't working either (but it isn't just vertical lines, it doesn't seem to be working on any line that isn't horizontal).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I know and I would, but I'm new here and I don't yet have the reputation to comment to other's posts... This was the only way I could make a meaningful contribution to progress this issue...