# Get distance between current position and calculated route

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've a question.
I want to calculate the distance between a current position and a calculated route. I'm using the Google Maps API v3 to calculate the route. I've tried to use google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge, but it didn't worked.

Here is my code:

```
directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){

        var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
            paths:new Array(result.routes[0].overview_path)
        });

        var currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(51.574470000000005, 4.32713);

        if(google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(currentPosition, poly)){
            console.log("On route");    
        }else{
            console.log("Not on route");
        }

        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            polylineOptions: {
                strokeColor: color,
                strokeWeight: 3
            }
        });

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);

    }
});
```

I'm not sure this is the good way to get the result I want.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you might want to set the tolerance in the `isLocationOnEdge` method. Maybe the point is just a little off. The default tolerance is 10^-9 wich is pretty small. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=de) for more details.

Do you really need the distance to the route? Or is it enough to know if the marker is on your route?

If so you might want to check out this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113399/google-maps-api-v3-islocationonedge-doesnt-work)

It is advised there to use the `containsLocation()` method.

If you really want to calculate the distance, then i have to say this is not possible according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750122/compute-the-distance-between-polyline-route-and-marker-in-google-maps-api-v3)

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try it. Keep you up to date!

Comment: It works! the problem was the overview path.

// Check if location is on route
    if(!google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(
     new google.maps.LatLng(received_data['latitude'], received_data['longitude']), 
     new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: result.routes[0].overview_path}), 
      .00001 * reach)){}